# add padding in table rows in html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create table rows start from different position like that

```
12345
 678910
```

my code

```
<table class="center">
  <tr style="padding-right: 22%">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="padding-left:18px">
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but padding didn't work at all

Comment: then don't use table, this is clearly not a table use case

Comment: tr cannot have margin and padding values.

Comment: what should i use then?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add number of empty columns to beginning of rows.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('table');

var rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');

var i = 0;
var j = 0;

for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerText = ' ';
    rows[i].prepend(td);
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table" class="center">

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td>e</td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be linked to the default display value set for `<tr>` elements.
If you set `display:block` on the `<tr>` element, the padding property should work.

```
<table class="center">
    <tr style="display:block">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:block; padding-left=10px">
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The result should be :

```
1 2 3 4 5
  6 7 8 9 10
```

However, not sure if using this `display` prop does not break anything in the `table` element.

Comment: changing the displat of tr will break the table layout

Comment: Hello !
Do you have any example where the `display:block` break the `table` layout ? 
Quick tests done on my side does not show any change on the table layout :)

Comment: Okk ! Indeed, this is not the intended behavior ^^